# value of optional type "CGContext?" not unwrapped

Tags: swift, swift3, cgcontext

I try to draw a line in the view, but my code fail to complier due to optional type error. I am new to swift and objective-c and spend many hours to search answer. The issue does not fix so far. So, Can anyone provide some clue to fix this issue?

Code:

```
import UIKit

class DrawLines: UIView {

       // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
         //Drawing code
        // context
      let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
      CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.0)
      CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.purpleColor().cgColor)

      //create a path
      CGContextMoveToPoint(context,0,0)
      CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,250,320)

    }
}
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: Simply to use **Fix-it** option by clicking on it.

Comment: @NiravD Thank your for answering. It maybe fix the issue by your suggest, but it does not solve my problem. Can you tell me the reason that causes this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't solve my problem, after fix-it will remove the error that you are currently getting.

Comment: @NiravD  The error gone, but my code is changed. CGContextSetLineWidth change to context.setLineWidth. It seems that CGContextSet is never be used.

Comment: Check the @vadian answer for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just forced unwrap the context, it is 100% safe but solves only one issue.

From the documentation of [UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/1623918-uigraphicsgetcurrentcontext):

> The current graphics context is `nil` by default. **Prior to calling its `drawRect:` method, view objects push a valid context onto the stack, making it current**.

In Swift 3 (assumed from the `draw` signature) the graphics syntax changed significantly:

```
class DrawLines: UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        context.setLineWidth(3.0)
        context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.purple.cgColor)

        //create a path

        // context.beginPath()
        context.move(to: CGPoint())
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:250, y:320))
        // context.strokePath()

    }
}
```

PS: But to draw the line you should uncomment the `beginPath()` and `strokePath()` lines.

Comment: I remove ! from the end of UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext instead of adding ? at the end of context, the program can be complied and run. Is there any difference if I try this way?

Comment: An trailing exclamation mark is not always bad or unsafe. According to the documentation it's absolutely safe to add an exclamation mark. The question mark makes / keeps it optional.

Answer (score 4):

UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() returns optional, to use it in your example you need to call `context!`.
The best way to use it it wrap it in if-let:

```
if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
    // Use context here
}
```

or even better use guard let:

```
guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
// Use context here
```

Comment: The context is guaranteed to exist when using `UIView`

Answer (score 3):

In this case the solution is to use `!` when getting the context:

```
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
```

The app will crash when there is no current context which means you have done something very wrong.